# Why doesn't my simple Cocoa binding work?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding, kvc

Cocoa bindings, KVC, and KVO are starting to make my head hurt. All I want to do is have an NSTextField's value bound to the value of a property of my view controller. Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is a simplified version of what I've got going on.

**MyViewController.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyViewController : NSViewController

@property NSString *colorSpaceName;
@property IBOutlet NSTextField *colorSpaceLabel;

@end
```

**MyViewController.m:**

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize colorSpaceName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    // ...
    if ( self ) {
        [self.colorSpaceLabel bind:@"stringValue" 
                          toObject:self 
                       withKeyPath:@"colorSpaceName" 
                           options:nil];
    }
    // ...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to IB there is no 'stringValue" binding for `NSTextField` just a 'value' binding. Unless you are setting up your UI all in code the easiest thing to do is to use IB for bindings.

Select the `NSTextField` in the xib file. Then select the bindings tab in the utilities area to the right. The first binding listed should be `value`, expand it. From the popup menu select "File's Owner" as the object to bind to. Xcode will enter `self` into the Model Key Path field for you, just add `.colorSpaceName` to the end of the field and press return.

If you really must do the binding in code then Change `@"stringValue"` to `@"value"` and make sure that your outlet is connected in IB.

Note: If you are creating the UI in code there is no need to declare any of the elements as `IBOutlet` since that and `IBAction` are just keywords for IB to know what properties and methods to pay attention to.